# Timer not working properly? C#

Tags: c#

my timer isnt working properly.
Could someone tell me whats wrong?

```
    public void Timer()
    {

        DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now;
        if (DateTime.Now > targetDate)
        {
            int Now = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            string dtNow = Now.ToString();
            targetDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
            int targetdate = targetDate.Hour;
            string TD = targetdate.ToString();

            if (Now == targetdate){
            Vote();
            }
        }

    }
```

It should run the vote function when the target date is equal to the time Now.

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: In most cases, `DateTime.Now` will not be larger than `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: vote will never run becouse datetime.now never bigger than datetime.now

Comment: This looks like it is comparing whether the code runs in the same hour.  Is that correct?

Comment: Is "targetDate" a time traveler?

Comment: Even compilers have feelings. Yours probably said no to that piece of code.

Comment: As @Groo said, `DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now;  if (DateTime.Now > targetDate)` is *generally* equal to `if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Now)` when used as in your code

Comment: "It should run the vote function when the target date is equal to the time Now" - do you mean `targetDate` or `targetdate` or `TD`, and `DateTime.Now` or `Now` or `dtNow`? Use variable names that make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to be rude, but I think you are confusing what you have done, which is to create a method by the name of "Timer" with the concept of creating an object of Type Timer (as in [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) which you might then create a delegate for the tick event to test the current time and invoke the vote method...

In short, the problem is you are way off course...

Answer (score 1):

The time clock of your PC is very slow compared to the CPU clock frequency which is responsible for the execution speed of your code. This means that a lot of code can be executed until the time clock makes its next **tick**.

---

UPDATE:

Also, I do not understand your logic. If you want to vote every minute, you should do something like this

```
private DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);

public void Timer() 
{   
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    if (now > targetDate) { 
        targetDate = now.AddMinutes(1); 
        Vote(); 
    } 
}
```

However, using a `System.Timers.Timer` as Cos Callis suggests, seems more appropriate.